# How to make marginratio from geometry package work also with LaTeX3?

Tags: geometry, latex3, catcodes

With `LaTeX2e`, the `marginratio` key provided by `geometry` package can be used safely:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\mylayoutwidth}
\newlength{\mylayoutheight}

\setlength{\mylayoutwidth}{170mm}
\setlength{\mylayoutheight}{240mm}

\geometry{%
  layoutsize={\mylayoutwidth,\mylayoutheight}
  ,textwidth=\mylayoutwidth*3/4
  ,textheight=\mylayoutheight*3/4
  ,marginratio={4:6,5:7}
}

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

But the same kind of code expressed in the `LaTeX3` way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutwidth_dim  { 170mm}
\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutheight_dim { 240mm}

\geometry{
  layoutsize={\c_my_layoutwidth_dim,\c_my_layoutheight_dim}
  ,textwidth=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,textheight=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,marginratio={4:6,5:7}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

fails with the error:

```
Runaway argument?
4:6\relax \ifnum \@tempcntb >\z@ \else \Gm@warning {margin ratio a:b \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \Gm@sep@ratio.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex^^M

?
```

I guess this comes from colon catcode in `LaTeX3` but is it possible to make `marginratio` work also with LaTeX3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:` has catcode 11 inside of `\ExplSyntax...`.  You have to spawn a `:` of catcode 12 in the marginratio by replacing `:` with `` \char_generate:nn { `\: } { 12 } ``.  Alternatively, you can define a macro to expand to the colon of catcode 12.  The best solution though is to use the predefined constant `\c_colon_str` which is a colon of catcode 12.  There are more constants for the “special” symbols of TeX, such as percent, ampersand, or circumflex, all of catcode 12.  Part XII, section 6 of the LaTeX3 interfaces [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) has a list.

*Edit:*  As of Jean-François' [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277562/10995) I corrected the width/height confusion.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutwidth_dim  { 170mm}
\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutheight_dim { 240mm}

\geometry{
  layoutsize={\c_my_layoutwidth_dim,\c_my_layoutheight_dim}
  ,textwidth=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,textheight=\c_my_layoutheight_dim*3/4
  ,marginratio={4 \c_colon_str 6, 5 \c_colon_str 7}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is already `\c_colon_str`

Comment: @egreg Ah, of course you are right, thank you!  That documentation is just so large that I always overlook something.

Comment: Can you please change the code? In any case it should not be called `\colon_other` and it should be a token list constant, if not a string.

Comment: @egreg that's new, isn't it? Actually interface3 says »New: 2016-09-19« :)

Comment: @clemens The team is so advanced… `:-D`

Answer (score 3):

You can also simply prefix the colons with `\string` (but note the space...).

Notice that your OP had a typo in the LaTeX3 part, using width for the height... thus skip to the bottom of this answer for the fix and skip the confusing discussion in-between which I leave here a testimony of how to lose one's time.

---

SKIP THIS!

But something seems to be wrong (also with the code of @HenriMenke's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277559/4686): if I add package `layout` the use of `\geometry` with `\ExplSyntaxOn/\ExplSyntaxOff` generates 6 pages not 3 pages.

*And the issue is there also with package `layout` not used, just check the log for the geometry parameters, particularly `\topmargin` and `\textheight`*

I don't know the cause (*) but indeed the page parameters differ:

<strike>(*) perhaps this is caused by</strike>

```
\mylayoutwidth=\skip52
\mylayoutheight=\skip53
```

versus

```
\c_my_layoutwidth_dim=\dimen144
\c_my_layoutheight_dim=\dimen145
```

i.e. the use of `\dimen` rather than `\skip` (=LaTeX's length) ?. I don't know LaTeX3 hence do not know what one should do to use `\skip`'s there and check is that is indeed the issue

(**update**: or rather not at all: evidently just replacing "`dim`" by "`skip`" is the syntax, but it does not change anything to the observed problem).

without LaTeX3 syntax:

[image: layout of a page]

with LaTeX3 syntax (either the one here with `\string` or the one from @HenriMenke's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277559/4686)):

[image: layout of a page with l3 syntax for \geometry]

As one can see there are differences for `\topmargin` and `\textheight`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layout}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutwidth_dim  { 170mm}
\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutheight_dim { 240mm}

\geometry{
  layoutsize={\c_my_layoutwidth_dim,\c_my_layoutheight_dim}
  ,textwidth=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,textheight=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,marginratio={4\string :6,5\string :7}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\layout % gives different results if \geometry used with l3 syntax or not ...

Foo.
\end{document}
```

---

Code with OP's typo fixed...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutwidth_dim  { 170mm}
\dim_const:Nn \c_my_layoutheight_dim { 240mm}

\geometry{
  layoutsize={\c_my_layoutwidth_dim,\c_my_layoutheight_dim}
  ,textwidth=\c_my_layoutwidth_dim*3/4
  ,textheight=\c_my_layoutheight_dim*3/4
  ,marginratio={4\string :6,5\string :7}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

No issues then.

Comment: The difference is due to a typo in Denis code: it sets the height with the layout*width*  value.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I had spotted this just before your comment and was editing my post. Maybe I should now do something useful like clean up my kitchen ?

Comment: @jfbu Sorry! Do you want me to fix my code?

Comment: @Denis: bad boy! well I fixed it in my answer, which all visitors will of course elect to read with gratitude `;-)`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé thanks, I have now cleaned up my kitchen thanks to you ! now next is to clean up my desk...